# Sufficient initial conditions for "Non-local" PDE

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I am studying a problem of the form $$i\, \partial_t \psi(t) = L \psi(t) + \int_0^t U(t-r) \psi(r) \, dr, \qquad \psi(0) = \psi_0,$$ where the evolution occurs in some Hilbert space, $L$ is a self-adjoint differential operator and $U(\cdot)$ is a time-dependent family of differential operators. I would like to know if the initial condition given above is sufficient for well-posedness (or at least, to determine a solution) or if one requires more information.

In particular, any references to papers/books where these types of integro-differential PDEs have been studied would be appreciated. I am calling this thing "non-local" as the time derivative on the left hand side is not "local" in the sense that it does not depend only on information about the solution at time $t$, but depends on the solution from $0$ to $t$. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions, we begin by reformulating the integro-differential equation into an integral equation. Integrating both sides of the equation from $0$ to $t$ and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus along with the initial condition $\psi(0) = \psi_0$, we obtain $$\psi(t) = \psi_0 - i \int_0^t L \psi(s) ds - i \int_0^t \int_0^s U(s-r) \psi(r) dr ds$$ This reformulation is crucial as it allows us to define an appropriate operator and apply fixed-point techniques.
Next, we define the operator $\mathcal{T}$ on the Banach space $C([0,T],H)$, equipped with the sup-norm $|\cdot|{C([0,T],H)}$, as $$(\mathcal{T} \psi)(t) = \psi_0 - i \int_0^t L \psi(s) ds - i \int_0^t \int_0^s U(s-r) \psi(r) dr ds$$), where $T > 0$. Our goal is to show that $\mathcal{T}$ is a contraction mapping for sufficiently small $T$. To this end, we consider $\psi_1, \psi_2 \in C([0,T],H)$ and use the boundedness of $L$ and the strong continuity of $U$ to obtain the estimate $$|\mathcal{T} \psi_1 - \mathcal{T} \psi_2|{C([0,T],H)} \leq (T |L| + T^2 \max_{t \in [0,T]} |U(t)|) |\psi_1 - \psi_2|{C([0,T],H)}$$ The strong continuity of $U$ ensures that $\max{t \in [0,T]} |U(t)| < \infty$, and thus, for $T$ small enough, we can guarantee that $$(T |L| + T^2 \max_{t \in [0,T]} |U(t)|) < 1$$, making $\mathcal{T}$ a contraction mapping.
Since $C([0,T],H)$ is a complete metric space and $\mathcal{T}$ is a contraction, we can apply the Banach Fixed Point Theorem to conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ has a unique fixed point $\psi \in C([0,T],H)$. This fixed point is the unique mild solution of the integral equation and, consequently, the integro-differential equation on the interval $[0,T]$.
To extend the solution to the entire interval $[0,\infty)$, we iterate the process on successive intervals $[T, 2T]$, $[2T, 3T]$, and so on. The uniqueness of solutions on each subinterval guarantees the uniqueness of the extended solution on $[0,\infty)$.